# NeoMAD application UI design with drag and drop components

Tags: user-interface, drag-and-drop, mobile-application, neomad

I am using NeoMAD for my mobile application development project. I want to start designing the UI of my application with drag and drop components. How do I open that view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible to design the application UI by drag and dropping components with NeoMAD.

To design the UI of your NeoMAD application, you can:

- use the NeoMAD XML Layout resource type to define the UI elements in XML,
- directly code the UI in your application Java source code using the classes of the com.neomades.ui package of the NeoMAD Generic API,
- or mix these two solutions.